# How do I handle decimals is razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Hi I'm trying to learn razor (core) and started with this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Now first problem is **decimal** handeling

In my model->Movies I have this property:

```
Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
public  decimal Price { get; set; }
```

When I create a new item and give it a price of 1
It shows as 1,00

If I try to edit the price to 1,1
I get this error: The field Price must be a number.
(If I change tha value in the database to 1,01, and try to change it to 1,02 in the UI I get the same error)

I live in Denmark we use **,** as decimal seperator

If I try with 1**.**1 it saves and shows as 11

Now how and here do I make the change?
On the model property or is there some application wide option or how do I control what is the decimal seperator?

I hope I don't have to change in the create, edit and details pages.
I think that could introduce a lot of possible errors when building a real world application?

In the edit.cshtml there is this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Movie.Price" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Movie.Price" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: In C# code, numbers always use dot `.` as separator. When you display it (by calling `ToString`) you can set a culture, that will display comma `,` instead. You can also define how many decimal digits, you want.